# upload image from another domain url to my server

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, canvas

I  am running angularjs and laravel and planing to upload users profile on facebook to my server and load it on the canvas.

Because the canvas has issues of **CORS** when other domain is loaded while changing it to **dataUrl**.

So what is the best way to get the image data on facebook after getting url of the image on fb domain to upload it to my server

Comment: you can do file_get_contents()

Answer (score 1):

First you must get the profile picture URL from the API.
For that you must request to `http://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=picture`, providing your access token.

It shall return something like:

```
{
  "picture": {
    "data": {
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpt1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/picture.jpg"
    }
  },
  "id": "10000userid"
}
```

So you must get only the interesting part:

```
// requesting
$get = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=picture&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE');

// parsing
$get = json_decode($get);

// getting the part you want
$picture_url = $get->picture->data->url;
```

After getting the image URL from Facebook API, you just have to:

```
// download it
$download = file_get_contents($picture_url);

// get extension (I'm not sure if Facebook really converts everything to JPEG, I'm not a huge Facebook user)
$extension = strtolower(end(explode(".", $download)));

// save it on your server
file_put_contents('path/to/save.'.$extension, $download);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'https://yourimageurl.com/test.png';
$img = 'foo.png';
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!